# Выводятся нули в консоль в Java

Tags: java, классы, конструктор

```
class Parent {
    int i;
}
public class Relative extends Parent{
public int i;
    public Relative (int a, int b) {
        a = super.i;
        b = i;
    }
    public void tell() {
        System.out.println(super.i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Relative object = new Relative(2, 6);
   object.tell();
}
}
```

Результат:

```
0
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

У Вас `int i` никак не инициализирована, то есть  переменная принимает значение по умолчанию, `0`, а потом Вы ее значение присваивайте переменным `a` и `b`. (`super.i` и `i` в данном случае указывают на одну и ту же переменную)